# How to disallow click function when current class is inactive with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

When in mobile view, the hamburger menu appears and the user clicks the icon it opens, when you click the close icon. its closes.

I'm attempting to allow users to click outside of the menu to close the menu. Unfortunately the JS code provided above, Allows users to click Anywhere on the site, to Open & close the menu. I Don't want this, I just want the menu to be closed when a user clicks outside of it.

How can I achieve this? Any help is appreciated.

```
document.querySelector('#bg-close').addEventListener('click', function() {
    document.querySelector('.nav').classList.toggle('nav-container')
})
```

The issue I'm attempting to solve is on my [website](https://blacklist-rs.com/design/)

> Summary:
>
> Hamburger menu is being activated with a click anywhere on the site.

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do, could yo make a snippet of your attempt or give more context?

Comment: Should of better explained myself.

I've used JavaScript indeed rather, Using this code.
`document.querySelector('#bg-close').addEventListener('click', function() {
    document.querySelector('.nav').classList.toggle('nav-container')
})`

Attempting to close the hamburger menu with a click outside of the current class. I've updated my [website](https://blacklist-rs.com/design/) where the example of what i'm trying to do is there. Although this opens the menu with a click anywhere. Trying to stop this. Thanks

Comment: I'm trying to understand what you want, but I'm still not sure. Have you consider using Bootstrap for your project? It's way easier to implement and you can play with cool JS events. Take a look to these navbars with responsive hamburger menu https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/navbar/

Comment: Appreciate it, I'm a little too far into my project to implement bootstrap.

I'll explain it as simply as i can.
When in mobile view, The hamburger menu appears. When you click the icon it opens, when you click the close icon. its closes. I'm attempting to allow users to click outside of the menu to close the menu. Unfortunately the JS code provided above, Allows users to click Anywhere on the site, to Open & close the menu. I Don't want this, I just want the menu to be closed when a user clicks outside of it.

Comment: You do not need to use jQuery for that task. Just use plain JS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can implement something like below:**

It uses an if statement to see if the `.nav-open` class is active, in case is not there, nothing will happen. In opposite case it will be removed.

```js
$('#bg-close').on('click', function() {
    let nav =  $('#navElement-id');
    if(nav.attr('class') == 'nav-container nav-open'){
       nav.attr('class','nav-container');
    }
});
```

```css
*{padding:0;margin:0}
#bg-close{height:100vh;width:100vw;background-color:blue}
.nav-container{color:blue; padding:10px;position:absolute;top:10px; left:0;}
.nav-open{color:black!important;background-color:grey;width:300px;height:200px}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="bg-close">
</div>
<div id="navElement-id" class="nav-container nav-open">Click on the blue</div>
```

Comment: Is jQuery really necessary for such a simple task?

Comment: I attempted to use Jquery in the first place, then used JS hence the edit on OP.

This worked perfectly, Just researched what attr does.

Comment: @Jarrod Hudson 1. In css selectors, replace hyphen with underscore. 2. Then try this (Vanilla JS): `bg_close.onclick = () => {if (navElement_id.classList.contains('nav_open')) navElement_id.classList.remove('nav_open');}`

Comment: @JarrodHudson the `attr()` jQuery method is super handy. It's good to be aware of it.

Comment: @JarrodHudson An even simpler solution, using [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining): `bg_close.onclick = () => navElement_id?.classList.remove('nav_open');`.